# Where apache's /tmp located?

Tags: filesystems, apache-httpd

I was just advised to re-ask my question from https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72795/command-execution-dvwa-creating-file-in-tmp here.

I use CentOS 7, and I'm trying to understand command execution attack. I found a tutorial which described a task to create a file. Simply using

```
cat /etc/passwd | tee -a /tmp/passwd
```

Should create copy of `/etc/passwd`. And it is (running `cat /tmp/passwd` from the same place, where I ran the previous command returns exactly what I was expecting). But there is no `/tmp/passwd` if I try to run this command from the server's terminal (not from the site).

I did no setup for apache and php.

Where should I search for the missing `/tmp/passwd`?

As @terdon asks:

```
mount | grep tmp
```

will return:

```
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=1966708k,nr_inodes=491677,mode=755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
/dev/sda7 on /tmp type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/sda7 on /var/tmp type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

Comment: It's possible that the apache instance is [chroot'd](http://www.linux-faqs.info/apache/running-apache-in-chroot-jail). In which case, it's going to be difficult for us to figure out what to tell you. If that's what's going on you just have to research the system.

Comment: What happens if you run `touch /tmp/foo; ls -l /tmp/foo` from the server?

Comment: @terdon it will show that there is no file with name /tmp/foo

Comment: @terdon very appreciate to you for editing!

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and include the output of `mount | grep tmp` please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Fedora 20, the directory you're looking for is in one of the (possibly multiple) `/var/tmp/systemd-private-${FOO}` folders. I haven't been able to verify that on a RHEL 7 or CentOS 7 system yet, but I strongly suspect it will be in the same `/var/tmp/systemd-private-${FOO}` area.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll check after a while. And where it's described? One thing I have found, it's in php_config, where it told to place some /tmp files right in system /tmp folder. So I think it's the same /tmp...

Comment: $ sudo find /tmp -name 'SOMEFILE' =>
/tmp/systemd-private-7GE1Zo/tmp/SOMEFILE

Answer (score 14):

It is from a feature of systemd called PrivateTmp.

```
/var/tmp/systemd-private-*
```

is `/var/tmp` for the service with `PrivateTmp` option set in the `.service` file.

```
/tmp/systemd-private-*
```

is `/tmp` for the service.

If `httpd` writes something to `/tmp`, it will be in `/tmp/systemd-private-*-httpd.service-*`.

The differences between `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` are

> The /var/tmp directory is made available for programs that require temporary files or directories that are preserved between system reboots. Therefore, data stored in /var/tmp is more persistent than data in /tmp.
>
> Files and directories located in /var/tmp must not be deleted when the system is booted. Although data stored in /var/tmp is typically deleted in a site-specific manner, it is recommended that deletions occur at a less frequent interval than /tmp.

Comment: systemd isn't worth the pain it causes. Two hours of I my life I won't get back trying to find where the /tmp files were going.

Answer (score 3):

My approach is to find the PID of the running apache process

```
ps ax | fgrep http
```

Look for some plausible PID numbers in the left hand column. Then access the /tmp directory via the PID path through /proc which is kind of ugly but saves time figuring out who has found a new and exciting way to mess up the system this version.

```
ls -l /proc/12345/root/tmp
```

Those are the files that the httpd process is seeing.